# Angular 7.2.15 + three 0.105.2 not working after three.js upgrade

Tags: angular, three.js

I have updated angular from V-7.2.5 to V-7.2.15 and three.js from V-0.101.2 to V-0.105.2 and I have got all sort of errors that I don't know how to fix:

> **THREE.Box3** method **.getSize()** gives "*error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.*"
>
> **.material.dispose()** gives "*error TS2339: Property 'dispose' does not exist on type 'Material | Material[]'.*"
>
> **.material.color.set(0x00cc00);** gives "*error TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Material'.*"
>
> **.object.material** gives "*error TS2339: Property 'material' does not exist on type 'Object3D'.*"

there are some fixes suggested for some of the errors that I don't think are right, like typecasting some of the variable as ***any*** to force three to recognise methods. The result is that three js does not behave correctly.

Unfortunately the official documentation still describe the "old ways" for disposing material or does not explain how to initialise expected argument in order for the old code to work.

Did anybody managed to have the latest version of angular and three.js working together? Can you point me to a solution?

Thank you,

Dino

**LET ME CLARIFY**

I use a Box3 called aDomain to record the dimensions (space occupied) by objects loaded into the scene. It is dynamic and recalculated every-time a new object is loaded or deleted from the scene.

When I create clipping planes I need the size of them and I use the code:

```
size: [this.aDomain.getSize().z, this.aDomain.getSize().y],
```

this code is not working anymore as getSize() requires an argument but this does not make sense to me. I want the size of aDomain. What vector do I have to pass as argument? I am already calling a method of the object that I am interested in!

More worryingly are all the missing properties that brake my code. How do I replace them?

> this.aRenderState.clipping.planes[0].object.material.**dispose()**;
>
> this.filteredIntersects[0].object.**material**
>
> this.meshCollection[part].object.material.**clippingPlanes**

where:

**object** is a **THREE.Mesh**

I feel like I have to modify the whole app because of changes on the material type wasting months of development...

Comment: you mean [this page doesn't cover the changes](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide)?

Comment: yes, it does not explain how to initialise required parameters

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "initialize"? When a target object is required (e.g. `Box3.getSize()`, you just pass in a new `Vector3` object (as defined in the TS declaration file). There is nothing to initialize....

Comment: I Mugen87, I will amend my question to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to waste months of development. You just need to engage in a bit of ["Type Assertion"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), where you tell the compiler what type of variable you're expecting.

### Example:

`this.filteredIntersects[0].object.material`

When you access `.object`, the compiler expects you'll be getting an `Object3D`which does *not* have a `.material` property. If you know this will be a `Mesh`, you can assert what type you're expecting with:

`(<THREE.Mesh>this.filteredIntersects[0].object).material`

Now TS is forced to expect that the result from the parenthesis `()` is going to be a `Mesh`.

### Why is it like this?

This safety mechanism is important because it protects you from accessing properties that don't exist. What if the `Object3D` was a `Sprite, LineSegment, or Group` instead of a `Mesh`? You'd get errors at runtime. So you need to tell the compiler that you *know* what's in there.

### Fixing things:

The same can be done with all your other errors:

```ts
// Original:
blah.material.dispose()
// Asserted type:
(<THREE.Material>blah.material).dispose()

// Original:
bleh.material.color.set(0x00cc00);
// Asserted type
(<THREE.MeshBasicMaterial>bleh.material).color.set(0x00cc00);`
```

With `material.color`, keep in mind that [the basic Material class does *not* have a `.color` property](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material). You have to be specific with which kind of material you're using before you get access to `.color`. This is because materials like Phong, Basic, or Standard *do* have a `.color` property, but ShaderMaterial does not.